# @SessionAttributes в Spring не обновляется

Tags: java, spring-mvc, сессия

У меня есть два контроллера

```
@Controller
@SessionAttributes("user")
public class ControllerA {

    @PostMapping("/method_a")
    @ResponseStatus(code = HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT)
    public void methodA(@SessionAttribute User user, HttpSession session){

           //здесь происходит изменение юзера

         session.setAttribute("user", user);
    }
}

@Controller
@SessionAttributes("user")
public class ControllerB {

    @GetMapping("/method_b")
    public String methodB(@SessionAttribute User user){

    //user - старый

    }

}
```

Сначала происходит обращение к `methodA`, где я изменяю юзера и снова кладу в сессию, но затем при обращении к `methodB` юзер остался старый. Как правильно работать с `@SesionAttributes`

Comment: Смогли решить вопрос?

Comment: нет. пока не решил

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка кажется в том, что вы в `methodA(@SessionAttribute User user` пытаетесь вызвать не инициализированную `user` и кажется по этому у вас все ломается.
2. В `AController` аннотацию `@SessionAttributes("user")` нужно удалить.
Посмотрите код ниже, надеюсь вам поможет.

Вот рабочий код:

**AController**

```java
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Optional;

@RestController
public class AController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/method_a", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
    public Map methodA(HttpSession session,
                       @RequestParam(name = "name", required = false) Optional<String> name) {
        //здесь происходит изменение юзера
        User user = new User(name.orElse("Default"));
        session.setAttribute("user", user);
        session.setAttribute("value", name.orElse("Default"));

        System.out.println(user.getName());
        System.out.println(session.getId());

        return Collections.singletonMap("nameSet", user.getName());
    }
}
```

**BController**

```
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.SessionAttributes;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Map;

@RestController
@SessionAttributes("user")
public class BController {
    @GetMapping("/method_b")
    public Map methodB(@ModelAttribute User user) {
        return Collections.singletonMap("nameGet", user.getName());
    }
}
```

**User**

```
public class User {
    private String name;

    public User() {
    }

    public User(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Comment: что значит не иницилизированную. Она инициализирована и засунута в атрибуты сессии при авторизации.

Comment: @alex у меня же вашего кода нет, то что вы дали. Код обновил. Кажется вот это `@SessionAttributes("user")` из `AController` нужно удалить. А то один раз запись происходит, а дальше не обновляется

Comment: @alex хотя, возможно это не совсем то решение

Comment: @Farkhod_Daniyarov в общем вы правы. SessionAttributes мешала мне сохранять обновленного юзера или перезаписывала его, не знаю точно. Вообще, как я понял эта аннотация нужна чтоб сохранить атрибуты модели в сессии, когда мы делаем так : model.addAttribute("user", user). Так что её нужно оставлять или только в контроллере авторизации или вообще убрать и просто делать так: session.setAttribute("user", user), как я и сделал

Comment: @alex рад что помогло, хотя я тоже не очень то и понял, как это все работает, как-то не логично, более детальнее нужно просмотреть.